# Equality search on heap == 0.5BD ?!?

Tags: database

I stumbled upon some cs notes claiming that the cost of an equality search(seek) on a heap is 0.5 B * D, where be B is the number of DB pages and D the average disk time.

Thinking it was some kind of error I found MORE cs notes claiming the same thing. One of them, had as  a side note the he was speaking on  a "key", ... ie exactly one match, but you can't know uniqueness without an index. In his heap insertion cost doesn't scan the heap for duplicates. If they're talking about the `row_id` then by the moment you know the `row_id`,  seeking should be about  as fast as  a `key lookup`, so again no. Has anyone any insights about what are they talking about?

Comment: This question would probably be more on-topic on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ or https://cs.stackexchange.com/ (but make sure to read their rules first!)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's about average cost: in best case, the search time is `D` as the first result is the one you are looking for. In worst case, it's `B * D`, as the very last result is the relevant one. Averaged, it's just `0.5 * B * D`